# How to run my Flask server so i can get to it with my domain name?

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, https

i currently have a very small http server and i would like to add it to my vm in google cloud platform, and then be able to access it with my domain name connected to it. But my server does not have permission to be on port 443 because it is already occupied how can I change this?

ERROR:

````
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: off
Address already in use
Port 443 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.```
````

SCRIPT:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/") #home page
def home():
    return "Hello! this is the main page <h1>HELLO<h1>"

@app.route("/admin")
def admin():
    return redirect(url_for("home"))

@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}<h1>"



@app.route('/login', methods=["POST","GET" ])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form['id']
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return 'GET'    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0',443)
```

Comment: An application listening on ports lower than 1024 requires elevation (privilege). Do not run a Flask app with elevation (sudo on Linux). The correct method is to install a webserver such as Apache or Nginx in front of your app or a load balancer in front of your instance.

Comment: Your Flask app is trying to listen on port 443. However, your app has done nothing to setup a secure listener. I do not recommend implementing SSL/TLS in Flask. Offload SSL to a webserver or load balancer.